# In chapter 148 of Tokyo Revengers, why did she die?

Tags: tokyo-revengers

In chapter 148 of *Tokyo Revengers*,

> Why did Emma die by just one hit on her head,

while the other characters can live longer even though being hit heavier?

Answer (score 3):

Well, I'll assume that this one was because of the speed of the bike that Kisaki was on. It surely didn't seem slow, and he probably putted a lot of strength in it, they didn't make into the hospital in time, she probably had a craneal traumatism and yah...
Well about the rest not dying with all those hits, I'd say they have some strong heads lmao. (Very probably plot armor as well)